# Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable iff $A^{m}$ is diagonalizable for $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an invertible matrix.

Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable iff $A^{m}$ is diagonalizable for $m \in \mathbb{N}$

I have proved that if $A$ is diagonalizable then $A^{m}$ is diagonalizable.

But I didn't know how to prove that if $A^{m}$ is diagonalizable for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Yes. Thank you!!

Comment: Which is the same as your other direction: _if $A^m$ is diagonalizable for $m\in N$, then $A$ is diagonalizable_. S

Comment: User767941, I spent two seconds on finding the answer, please, search the site.

Comment: Let's use $\mathbb{R^+}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$ for the exponent $m$ (there's no real problem in $m$ being a real instead of just a natural). Use the variable change $A^m=B$. Then $A=B^{1/m}$. So, for what you proved, $B$ diagonalizable implies $B^{1/m}$ also diagonalizable, and we have finished, because if it's true for $m\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$).